# How I can use ReportViewer with VS Express

Tags: reportviewer, visual-studio-express

I have no money to buy Visual Studio so I use the express edition
I want to use Microsoft ReportViewer
Is it legal to use ReportViewer without buying VS and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6442)

I'm unsure whether this means you can use it in visual studio, nor am I certain about the licensing.

I haven't used express edition for a little while. I'm guessing the control is in the download, you could try adding one of the dll's as a control.

I believe that you can use [Reporting Services in SQL Server Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365166%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (which is free), which might indicate the validity of using ReportViewer in vs express.

Comment: Thank you, I got the Reportviewer control works by adding reference to the files `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll` and `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll`
which I grab from old project bin/Debug, But I don't know if that's legal or not

Comment: I'm guessing the redistributable package will have some terms & conditions to read through.

Answer (score 2):

i had some luck installing the [Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6442) (from above) and then:

1. going to the form designer
2. right clicking on the toolbox and clicking add items
3. browsing for the DLL (which is located at `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll`

report viewer should then be available from the toolbox